# squareArea is not a function when requiring module

Tags: javascript, node.js

I made a set of functions and none of them is working. Here's one of them, for example:

```
function squareArea(side) {
  var sArea = side * side;
  return sArea;
}
```

And this is how I `require` the module:

```
var mfs = require("m-p-formulas-js");
var test = mfs.squareArea(2);
console.log(test)
```

It returns this error:

```
TypeError: mfs.squareArea is not a function
```

What should I do to solve this?

Comment: Log out `mfs` and see if it's importing correctly, or if you're calling it correctly

Comment: Is it `node.js` environment ? Please insert tag. What is your folder tree ? Please `console.log( mfs )`.

Comment: my guess you are not exporting it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You aren't exporting the function so it doesn't exist on the `require`d module object. Assuming you're using ES5, use [`module.exports`](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_module_exports) which contains the module's exports:

```
function squareArea(side) {
  var sArea = side * side;
  return sArea;
}
module.exports = {
  squareArea: squareArea
};
```

You could also shorten it to this using the [`exports`](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_exports_shortcut) shortcut:

```
exports.squareArea = squareArea;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to export the function to make it available to others. Add the following to the bottom of your definition of `m-p-formulas-js` module:

```
module.exports = {
    squareArea
}
```